# How to distinguish whether login is from Adobe AIR desktop app or from chrome Flash plugin

Tags: flash, air

We are modifying our GUI to Adobe flash AIR desktop application. Previously it was chrome/firefox based flash plugin, but since chrome won't support flash plugin after 2020, we are modifying our code. But we can still use harman pluggin which will act as a wrapper to support the flash within chrome. And hence in our GUI code we need to support both flash plugin and Adobe AIR application.

Our login code has the following line -

```
 url = UrlHelper.getBaseUrlForMain() + serviceConfigUrl;
```

Here we need to check whether this code is executed from Adobe AIR or flash plugin and accordingly we need to execute different code.

So can you please tell me how to implement that check?
One is desktop app and ther other is crome/firefox plugin.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the simplest way is to check **root.loaderInfo.url** variable and see it it starts from "http" (browser plugin) or not (AIR application). Alternately, you can compose a class which uses AIR-only functionality, like checking **File.permissionStatus**, then run this code in the **try...catch** clause and see if it fails (browser plugin) or not (AIR application).

Comment: Hi @Organis: thanks a lot for resolving this issue. We are using FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.loaderInfo.url and if it contains "app", then it's AIR application, otherwise it's browser plugin. Thanks.